# Resume VPN after hibernation (sleeping mode) vs real IP detection

Tags: vpn, ip

Imagine I am using VPN service app on my PC and I am logged into a website. Then the PC enters sleep mode.

Disconnection sequence of sleep mode I suppose: first browser, second VPN. And for re-start mode: first VPN, second browser.

When the PC wakes up, will the VPN start first? Is there any way the website can register my real IP? Or just once my PC is being re-started during any of this disconnection/connection process?

Comment: I had a difficult time understanding your question, so I took a stab at rewording it,

Comment: Note that _in most cases_ (but not all), leaving sleep mode will not make the browser a communicate with the website.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the VPN could become disconnected during the resume, and traffic could be sent by the browser without using the VPN. This behavior may be unpredictable, but if revealing your true IP address is undesirable (i.e. part of your threat model), you will want to defend against it happening.

A common way to mitigate this is to create firewall rules that prevent non-VPN traffic from leaving your computer. Some VPN  applications may provide a similar option as a feature.

Comment: Sleep does not shut processes down, does it? It stores the OS state? In that case, there is no teardown or rebuild order. Everything comes up as it was, yes?

Comment: @schroeder My thoughts exactly; I was more thinking that the VPN may become disconnected briefly when things resume, and if one is worried about any traffic leaking, it should likely be considered.